# Using keyboard and gaming mouse simultaneously freezes games

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse, 18.10

This starts happening eventually after every time I reboot. When using the keyboard and a button on my mouse other than the primary/secondary/scroll wheel, the game will freeze for a couple of seconds. If I spam buttons I can keep the screen perpetually frozen, but from the sound I can tell that the game is still running. Once the problem appears it happens in every game (and Firefox) until I reboot. Some games I can list off are CS:GO, Warframe, Overwatch, Minecraft, 7 Days to Die, and Garry's Mod (native and Proton). I found [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_buttons), but an xorg.conf is not located at /etc/X11/ and I cannot find any useful search results from there.

Tested with every kb/m combination of the following keyboards/mice:

- Redragon K552
- Corsair Vengeance K95 RGB
- Redragon Perdition
- Corsair Scimitar Pro RGB

Specs:

- Ubuntu 18.10
- i7-4770k
- GTX 1080
- Nvidia Driver 418.43
- Kernel 4.18.0-16-generic

Please help me figure out what my next troubleshooting steps should be.

Edit: Moved from gnome to KDE and the issue is no longer present.