# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes with gaming mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, games, freeze

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 (new user in Linux), I have a [Logitech G600](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g600-mmo-gaming-mouse.910-002864.html) that has a lot of extra buttons on it.
Every time i do an input in the extra buttons in the mouse (from g6-g20) at the same time im using my keyboard ALL MY PC just freezes.  I don't know what could be the source of the problem for this but if anyone knows where i can get more information about this or a workaround would be so appreciated.

This problem just happens when i hit the keyboard and the extra buttons at the same time, it doesn't happen if i just click a extra button by itself

Pretty much i have the same issue than in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129786/using-keyboard-and-gaming-mouse-simultaneously-freezes-games)

Here is the [log i get from using XEV](https://pastebin.com/PMgBPB6W) to get all the keystrokes.

Comment: open a terminal and execute `xev`. This tools shows you the keys from input (including mouse). Paste the contents of those events into your question, so we might see whats going on

Comment: I just added the log file in the question

Comment: Strange. Using xev I get: 'ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    root 0x1b6, subw 0x0, time 28298473, (66,149), root:(937,628),
    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7200001,
    root 0x1b6, subw 0x0, time 28298644, (66,149), root:(937,628),
    state 0x0, button 8, same_screen YES
' -> I do not see any "Button events" which i expected

Comment: Check [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjy8ZTyubfuAhXD8eAKHRH_A9kQFjAAegQICxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Flinux4noobs%2Fcomments%2Fe23m8n%2Flogitech_g600_mouse_not_working_properly_on_linux%2F&usg=AOvVaw13rF0Gv1QTlvvrxOye_Bbe) for possible solution